# Check if polynomials are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to check if polynomials $1, 1+t^2, 1+t+t^2$ are linearly independent.
My idea is:
$1 \to [1,0,0]$
$1+t^2\to [1,1,0]$
$1+t^2+t^3 \to [1,1,1]$
And now $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$
I would like to find rank of this array. Rank of this array is $3$ so columns are linearly independent.

Is it correct reasoning ?

Comment: The rank is $2$, but you've written the wrong matrix.

Comment: You could also just compute the determinant of the - afterall hopefully correct - matrix

Comment: Your polynomials mysteriously changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The coordinate vectors with respect to the basis $\{1,t,t^2\}$ are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the matrix you have to compute the rank of is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Swapping rows 2 and 3 brings it into unitriangular form, so the rank is $3$.

Alternatively you can observe that
$$
t=(1+t+t^2)-(1+t^2)\\
t^2=(1+t^2)-1
$$

Comment: So checking rank is ok ?

Comment: @Happyman Surely so! Provided you get the right matrix. `;-)`

Answer (score 11):

Just for fun you could use the definition of linear independence. That is, say that
$$
a(1) + b(1 + t^2) + c(1 + t + t^2) = 0.
$$
Then
$$
(a + b + c)1 + (c)t + (b + c)t^2 = 0. 
$$
Now you probably know that $\{1,t,t^2\}$ is linearly independent. So
$$
\begin{align}
c &= 0 \\
b + c &= 0 \Rightarrow b = 0 \\
a + b + c &= 0 \Rightarrow a = 0.
\end{align}
$$